# How to display D3 Color legend horizontally and not vertically

Tags: css, d3.js, legend

I am working on color legend using d3 and currently my legend is shown vertically but I want it to display horizontally. I have attached code snippet and also shared jsfiddle link.

```
    var svg = d3.select(selector_id)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", (legendheight) + "px")
    .attr("width", (legendwidth) + "px")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("left", "0px")
    .style("top", "0px")

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (legendwidth - margin.left - margin.right + 3) + "," + (margin.top) + ")")
    .call(legendaxis);
};
```

I want something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCxSa.png

I have also attached fiddle link for more info:

https://jsfiddle.net/shru90/e42vcLy0/17/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D I have edited my question to be more precise. Does it help now?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform: rotate(90deg) CSS or in JavaScript from this method

Use for
canvas, SVG

Comment: Thanks it worked though but still need to to do bit css change to align both svg and canvas properly. Anyway thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I have edited my question to be more precise. Does it help now? I see that i am not able to post more question in stack overflow